# Pandas DataFrame: how do we keep columns based on the index name?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I seem to run into some python or enumerate bugs that I am not quite sure how to fix it (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54487912/python-for-loop-enumerate) for more details). 
Long story short, I desire to see multiple data sets that has a column name of 0,4,6,8,10,12,14.

```
0   4   6   8   10  12
1   2   5   4   2   1  
5   3   0   1   5   10
....
```

But my current data looks like the following

```
0   4   2   6   8   10  12
1   2       5   4   2   1  
5   3       0   1   5   10
....
```

Therefore, I would like to add a code that keeps columns based on the index number (including only 0,4,6,8,10,12).

Is there a pandas function that can help with this?

Comment: So, your current data has an extra column you don't want? Do you have a list of columns you want to keep or ...?

Comment: Yes. I have a list of columns that I want to keep.

Comment: So you could just do `df.reindex(columns=cols_to_keep)`?

Comment: Are you trying to remove the columns which have na values? Or the number of columns is fixed no matter what?

Comment: @Naveen the column has na values.